# How to construct a list of requests based on the response of the first request in Scrapy?

Tags: python, scrapy

I want to scrape an API. The API will return some data and the total amount of data. I want to

1. first call the API once and get the total amount of data.
2. Then divide the total amount of data with the page size to get the total number of pages.
3. Next, construct a list of requests to be sent

But I am not sure how to do that in Scrapy. This is my `start_requests`

```
def start_requests(self):
        url = "https://hkapi.centanet.com/api/Transaction/Map.json" 

        page = 1

        headers = {
            'lang': 'tc',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
            'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
            'User-Agent': 'okhttp/4.7.2' 
        }

        payload = {
            "daterange": 180,
            "postType": "s",
            "refdate": "20200701",
            "order": "desc",
            "page": f"{page}",
            "pageSize": 100,
            "pixelHeight": 2220,
            "pixelWidth": 1080,
            "points[0].lat": 22.695053063373795,
            "points[0].lng": 113.85844465345144,
            "points[1].lat": 22.695053063373795,
            "points[1].lng": 114.38281349837781,
            "points[2].lat": 21.993328259196705,
            "points[2].lng": 114.38281349837781,
            "points[3].lat": 21.993328259196705,
            "points[3].lng": 113.85844465345144,
            "sort": "score",
            "zoom": 9.745128631591797,
            "platform": "android"
        }

        yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse, method="POST", headers=headers, body=json.dumps(payload))
```

This is my `parse`:

```
    def parse(self, response):
        json_response = json.loads(response.text)
        yield json_response
```

I think I can extract the total number of data and calculate the total number of page in the `parse` function. But how can I take that number and construct a list of payload?

For example, if the total number of page is 3. Then I will construct a list of payload with length 3. Then loop through the payloads.

Example JSON response:

```
    {
    "DITems":[],
    "TransactionCount": 34037,
    "Count": 34037,
    "MinPoint": {
        "Lat": 22.2390387561,
        "Lng": 113.9203349215
    },
    "MaxPoint": {
        "Lat": 22.5454478015,
        "Lng": 114.2243478859
    },
    "RoundTripNeeded": false
    }
```

Thanks! This is my first project using Scrapy!

Comment: Seem to be getting the json data with the script you have. What do you mean by URLS ? Are you want to send multiple requests for json data based on page numbers? If that's the case, it would be good if you provided that information. Lord knows json data hunting can be tedious at the best of times!

Comment: @AaronS Sorry for the confusion. Actually I mean a list of payload. I have placed a placeholder in the payload called `{page}`. So, if the first JSON response said it has in total 3 pages (actually I need to calculate that by dividing #data/page size), I will create a list of payloads (page 1,2,3) and yield the `response` in a loop.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, all you have to do is do a for loop around the payload and send a request based on that specific payload once you have the total number of pages from the first request.

### Update Based on Comments

I'm using `total_pages = json.loads(response.text)['total_pages']` as an example of accessing where the total pages within the json file within the `parse` function.

### Code Example

```
url = "https://hkapi.centanet.com/api/Transaction/Map.json" 
headers = {
          'lang': 'tc',
          'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
          'Connection': 'Keep-Alive',
          'User-Agent': 'okhttp/4.7.2' 
         }

first_payload = {
            "daterange": 180,
            "postType": "s",
            "refdate": "20200701",
            "order": "desc",
            "page": "1",
            "pageSize": 100,
            "pixelHeight": 2220,
            "pixelWidth": 1080,
            "points[0].lat": 22.695053063373795,
            "points[0].lng": 113.85844465345144,
            "points[1].lat": 22.695053063373795,
            "points[1].lng": 114.38281349837781,
            "points[2].lat": 21.993328259196705,
            "points[2].lng": 114.38281349837781,
            "points[3].lat": 21.993328259196705,
            "points[3].lng": 113.85844465345144,
            "sort": "score",
            "zoom": 9.745128631591797,
            "platform": "android"
           }  

def start_requests(self):
   
    yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, callback=self.parse, method="POST", headers=self.headers, body=json.dumps(self.first_payload))

def parse(self,response):
    total_pages = json.loads(response.text)['total_pages']
    for i in range(2,total_pages+1):
        page = i
        payload = {
           "daterange": 180,
           "postType": "s",
           "refdate": "20200701",
           "order": "desc",
           "page": f"{page}",
           "pageSize": 100,
           "pixelHeight": 2220,
           "pixelWidth": 1080,
           "points[0].lat": 22.695053063373795,
           "points[0].lng": 113.85844465345144,
           "points[1].lat": 22.695053063373795,
           "points[1].lng": 114.38281349837781,
           "points[2].lat": 21.993328259196705,
           "points[2].lng": 114.38281349837781,
           "points[3].lat": 21.993328259196705,
           "points[3].lng": 113.85844465345144,
           "sort": "score",
           "zoom": 9.745128631591797,
           "platform": "android"
          }
       yield scrapy.Request(url=self.url, callback=self.parse_new_requests, method="POST", headers=self.headers, body=json.dumps(payload))

def parse_new_requests(self,response):
    json_response = json.loads(response.text)
    yield json_response
```

### Explanation

We make a first request to grab the total_page variable. Then we define that `total_pages` within the parse function. We can then use that to make a for loop in `range(2,total_page+1)`, as we don't need the 1st page. Each specific payload is created and then we pass that payload onto `parse_new_requests`.

Comment: Yes. But the total_page changes. But the json response will have the total_page given. So, I need to get one of the resposnes in order to know how many pages to loop.

Comment: Can you tell me where in the json response the total_page number is ? Again I'd prefer not to have to do the json data hunting game if I have to and given you know this data better than anyone else, that information would be helpful. I've updated the code to reflect what you've said.

Comment: I have added an example response.

Comment: Let me know if that's what you were after.

Comment: Yes. Thank you!!
But it seems we need to add the url and header in the `parse` function as well.

and the `range` needs to start at 1. Since the response from `start_requests` will be missing.

Comment: Sorry, I forgot to mention, it's always best to keep variables that don't change outside the functions but within the spider class. You can refer to them with self.VARIABLE within your functions. Also if you've already got the response from page 1, you can  manipulate it in the parse function. Is it necessary to loop through that again ? I've updated the code.